# Show that isometries of $\mathbb{S^2}$ are determined by the image of three points $A,B,C$ not in a "line".

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, isometry, spherical-geometry

Given information: If points $P,Q \in \mathbb{S^2}$ have the same distace from three points $A,B,C \in \mathbb{S^2}$ not in a "line", then $P=Q$.

Deduce from the given information that an isometry of $\mathbb{S^2}$ is determined by the images of the three points $A,B,C$ not in a "line".

My understanding of the given information is that the points that are equidistant from $A,B,C$ are given by the intersection of three great circles. These three great circles intersect at two points, one is between the triangle spherical triangle $A,B,C$ and the other is it's antipodal point on the other side of the sphere. So we know that any point that is equidistant from $A,B,C$ by a given distance $k$ is unique. But how does this relate to isometries of $\mathbb{S^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d(X,Y)$ be the distance between points $X$ and $Y$.

Then the given information is saying that $d(P,A)=d(Q,A), d(P,B)=d(Q,B),$ and $d(P,C)=d(Q,C)$.  It's *not* saying that $P$ is equidistant from $A,B,C$ (and same for $Q$).

You are being asked to show that a point is uniquely determined by its distances from three points not in a line.

(Hint: assume that two distinct points $P$ and $Q$ have the same distances to three points not on a line, and see if you can get a contradiction).

(Hint 2: Draw the line that is equidistant from $P$ and $Q$.  Where are $A,B,C$ relative to that line?)

Comment: I am trying to do this by applying the distance formula in $R^3$ but it is getting very messy. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: @user: I added another hint.

Comment: either one or two of A,B,C are on the line, but not all three?

Comment: @user: why not all three? I mean, all three are equidistant from $P,Q,$ right?

Comment: Because we have given that A,B,C are not in a "line". Why do you say all three are equidistant from P,Q?

Comment: Sorry i'm honestly not the sharpest tool in the shed and all of this is super confusing. Would you be so kind and explain this in a really dumbed down way, maybe even visually?

Comment: All three are equidistant by the original assumption in the OP. So we’ve reached a contradiction, and conclude that our assumption $P\neq Q$ is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116514/discussion-between-brainjam-and-user140161).